# Lz4 compression is not splittable

Tags: hadoop, lz4

I am using lz4 compression and write data to a hive table, this table has  20 files and each is 15G on HDFS, and every file name of this table are ending with lz4, eg, `part-m-00000.lz4`.

When I run `select count(1)` from this table, it kicks off only 20 mappers, which mean `lz4 splittable` doesn't take effect.

It is said that lz4 supports splittable against text file,so I would ask what I should do or additional steps to enable this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can have some control on how data is being compressed, [this codec](https://github.com/carlomedas/4mc) might be closer to what you need, since it embeds a splittable layer. It's designed for use with Hadoop.

If you can't change the format, and it was compressed as a single stream with no jump-table, then I'm afraid there is no good solution. `lz4` CLI will, by default, split data into blocks of 4 MB, but does not provide any jump table. The jump table is what makes an archive easy to read in random order. Without it, it's necessary to stream the data, and distribute the blocks in order for later processing.